# How to grep VPS IP adress and put it to text file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I get (discover) my VPS IP adress, then grep it and then put it to file myinfo.txt to line "Here is my IP"

For example I dont know my IP, but I can use command ifconfig to know that. Task is to  write command which can get (discover) my IP and then put to specific line in tex file. After that if I open my text file, I must see:
text
mytext
text IP - here is my IP

I have found this command, but don't know how to correctly use it

```
IP=$(ip addr | grep 'inet' | grep -v inet6 | grep -vE '127\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | head -1)
read -p "IP address: " -e -i $IP IP
```

Comment: `read -a a < <(ip -4 -br addr sh eth0 2>&-); echo ${a[2]%/*}` shorter form, the array `a` contains interface state ip1 ip2 ...

Answer (score 0):

```
cat myinfo.txt | egrep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
```

---

`cat myinfo.txt` print the file

`|` pipe the results in the next command

`egrep -oE` find the pattern*

`'[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'` is the pattern, where :

- `[0-9]{1,3}` means "1 to 3 characters that is composed of digits
- `\.` escape the dot. Else, the dot is understand by the pattern as "whatever character you want (including dots, but also any of them : `abcdef`...)

---

**Edit :** `'[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}'` is shorter, since you have repeated pattern in your pattern. You can use `(` and `)` for that

---

If you often use that command, you might want to `alias` that command in your `.bashrc` file with

```
echo -e "alias egrep_ipv4=\"egrep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}'\"" >> $HOME/.bashrc`
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

And then you will just need to pipe your text to egrep_ipv4

`cat myinfo.txt | egrep_ipv4`

Comment: Thank for fast answer, but I think I did not ask thr question correctly. I corrected my question

Comment: can you write a sample of the output you want in your post ?